# Asynchronous function to get directory size (not including subdirectories)

Tags: javascript, promise

I neeed asynchronous function getDirSize, which counts the size of the passed directory (not including subdirectories). Tried to use `Promise.all` but I cannot write it without errors. spent about 2 hours and total stuck with it :(

```
import path from 'path';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { promises as fs } from 'fs';

const getDirSize = (directoryPath) => {
    return fs.readdir(directoryPath)
      .then(data => data.map((item) => fs.stat(item))
      .then((data2) => Promise.all(data2)
         .then())

      //_.sumBy(files, 'size'))
}
```

Jast have no idea how to write `Promise.all` to count file sizes. Should it work like this `.then((content) => Promise.all(content)`. Can anyone help?

It should return promise and work like this:

```
getDirSize('/usr/local/bin').then(console.log);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const getDirSize = async (directoryPath) => {
  return new Promise( (resolve,reject)=>{
        //counting logic here
        //resolve(datayouwanttopass) under some condition
        //reject(erroryouwanttothrow) under some condition
  } )
}
getDirSize('/usr/local/bin').then( (data)=>{
//handle your data here
})
.catch( (error)=>{
//error handling
})
```